# Is there a plugin to make "Go to Symbol in File..." fast for C++ files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The "Go to Symbol in File..." command in Visual Studio Code is really slow for C++ files. I'm coming from Sublime Text 3, which is super fast in this regard, but Sublime Text 3 also indexes the project, so I'm guessing that's the key. Does anyone know of a plugin that will do the same for Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the C/C++ extension is responsible for this, and there is a bug where the extension is searching the entire database rather than the just the file.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1472